# What is the "GlobalStatementSyntax" syntax node type in Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I was investigating classes of syntax nodes which implement `MemberDeclarationSyntax` in Roslyn and encountered `GlobalStatementSyntax` class.
What kind of code generates syntax tree with `GlobalStatementSyntax`nodes? And why `GlobalStatementSyntax` is derived from `MemberDeclarationSyntax`? Can such node represent a member of a type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two minutes of experimentation confirmed that you get those if you use the new [Top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#top-level-statements) feature. That is, if your entire program is:

```
Console.WriteLine(args.Count);
```

(With no `class`, no `void Main`, etc)

Then the [Roslyn Quoter](http://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net) generates this structure:

```
CompilationUnit()
.WithMembers(
    SingletonList<MemberDeclarationSyntax>(
        GlobalStatement(
            ExpressionStatement(
                InvocationExpression(
                    MemberAccessExpression(
                        SyntaxKind.SimpleMemberAccessExpression,
                        IdentifierName("Console"),
                        IdentifierName("WriteLine")))
                .WithArgumentList(
                    ArgumentList(
                        SingletonSeparatedList<ArgumentSyntax>(
                            Argument(
                                MemberAccessExpression(
                                    SyntaxKind.SimpleMemberAccessExpression,
                                    IdentifierName("args"),
                                    IdentifierName("Count"))))))))))
.NormalizeWhitespace()
```

Comment: Why is GlobalStatementSyntax derived from MemberDeclarationSyntax then?